# SQL Count of Agents providing profit every month

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

There are 2 columns in a table. AgentID and BusinessDate.

Query to find the count of Agents everymonth. But the count should only include agents having businessDate in every previous month.

Eg.

| AgentID | BusinessDate |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Jan 2020 |
| 2 | Jan 2020 |
| 3 | Jan 2020 |
| 4 | Jan 2020 |
| 5 | Feb 2020 |
| 1 | Feb 2020 |
| 2 | Feb 2020 |
| 3 | Feb 2020 |
| 6 | March 2020 |
| 7 | March 2020 |
| 1 | March 2020 |
| 2 | March 2020 |
| 2 | March 2020 |

Output

| Month | Count |
| --- | --- |
| Jan | 4 |
| Feb | 3 |
| Mar | 2 |

Only the agents providing business in every continuous month are counted.
I hope that I have explained the problem fine.

I have tried below methods:

```sql
select 
    Case 
         when (BusDate Between '01/01/2020' and '01/31/2020') and (BusDate Between '02/01/2020' and '02/28/2020')  then ID end as 'Month'
    ,BusDate

from #Temp
group by Case 
         when (BusDate Between '01/01/2020' and '01/31/2020') and (BusDate Between '02/01/2020' and '02/28/2020')  then ID end
         BusDate



select ID 
from #Temp where BusDate between '01/01/2020' and '01/31/2020' and BusFlg =1
intersect
select ID 
from #Temp where BusDate between '02/01/2020' and '02/28/2020' and BusFlg =1


select ID 
from #Temp where BusDate between '01/01/2020' and '01/31/2020'  BusDate between '02/01/2020' and '02/28/2020' and BusFlg =1


select Month(BusDate), Count(ID) Over (partition by Month(BusDate)) from #Temp
group by BusDate,ID

select Month(BusDate), Sum(case when BusDate between '01/01/2020' and '01/31/2020' then 1 
                                when Month(BusDate)=2 and BusDate between  '01/01/2020' and '01/31/2020' and 
    )
from #Temp where BusFlg=1
Group by Month(BusDate)


select distinct ID, Count(Distinct ID) AS Cnt from #Temp where Month(BusDate)=2 and 
ID in (Select Distinct ID from #Temp where Month(BusDate)=1 and BusFlg=1)
And BusFlg = 1 Group by ID
```

Comment: I have found the Count Separately for each month but not able to write a generic query.

Answer (score 1):

You can go for recursive CTE and only consider the already existing agents in the recursive part of the CTE. I am also going for rank to consider months in order: January, February ,March.

```sql
    declare @table table(agentId int, businessdate varchar(10))
    insert into @table values
         (1 ,'Jan 2020')
        ,(2 ,'Jan 2020')
        ,(3 ,'Jan 2020')
        ,(4 ,'Jan 2020')
        ,(5 ,'Feb 2020')
        ,(1 ,'Feb 2020')
        ,(2 ,'Feb 2020')
        ,(3 ,'Feb 2020')
        ,(6 ,'March 2020')
        ,(7 ,'March 2020')
        ,(1 ,'March 2020')
        ,(2 ,'March 2020')
        ,(2 ,'March 2020');

    ;

    with
        cte_months as(
            SELECT 1 as rnk, 'Jan 2020' as mon
            union all
            select 2, 'Feb 2020'
            union all
            select 3, 'March 2020'
        ),
        cte_agents as(
            SELECT cm.rnk, agentid, businessdate
            from
                @table as t
                    inner join cte_months as cm
                    on cm.mon = t.businessdate
            where cm.rnk = 1
            union all
            -- consider only new months
            SELECT cm.rnk, t.agentid, t.businessdate
            from
                @table as t
                    inner join cte_Agents as c
                    on c.agentid = t.agentid
                    --
                    inner join cte_months as cm
                    on
                        cm.mon = t.businessdate
                    and cm.rnk = c.rnk + 1
        )
    -- SELECT * FROM cte_agents
    SELECT
        businessdate,
        count(distinct AgentId) as countOfAgents
    FROM CTE_AGENTS
    group by businessdate
```

| businessdate | countOfAgents |
| --- | --- |
| Feb 2020 | 3 |
| Jan 2020 | 4 |
| March 2020 | 2 |

Answer (score 0):

You can dense rank the months and the agents by month.  Then take only rows where the ranks are equal.  Then aggregate:

```
select v.yyyymm, count(distinct agentid)
from (select t.*, v.yyyymm,
             dense_rank() over (order by yyyymm) as seqnum,
             dense_rank() over (partition by agentid order by yyyymm) as seqnum_agentid
      from t cross apply
           (values (datefromparts(year(businessdate), month(businessdate), 1))
           ) v(yyyymm) 
     ) t
where seqnum = seqnum_agentid
```

Comment: It is giving a Syntax error near v in line number 7. I am sorry but I am not able to fix it.